# Google Drive User Views

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sheets, google-docs-api

Is there a way to see who has viewed a specific Google Drive app (doc, sheets, forms, etc.), meaning see when a user looked at it (not edited it)? I assume this could only work if the privacy settings were enabled for specific users only (meaning they're logged in to Google Apps). I'm thinking this could be done through Google Scripts, but maybe it's a built-in feature, or the script already exists.

Answer (score 1):

If the File is in public mode, the user will remain anonymous, but if it is in private mode, you will see the person you have allowed to access the file.